# How to avoid parsing of data with google app script range.setValues

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm dealing with an annoying problem when importing data into Google Spreasheets using Google App Script
Basically the code is as follows:

```js
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(mySource,separator);
range.setValues(csvData);
```

usually this works perfectly but sometimes we have a `productcode` column which gets messed up

| productcode | value |
| --- | --- |
| 01DECUB003 | 100 |
| 21MAR003 | 200 |

The second row gets messed up because the product code is interpreted as a Date and thus converted into `21mar2003` which in turn does not match any of the real product code and then raises errors in further export scritps.

Is there any way to fix this? I don't see any relevant option neither within [Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv,-delimiter) nor within [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

Is there any alternative APIs for doing the same?

---

Here's an example which reproduces the issue

- create a new sheet and name the first (and only) tab "IMPORT"
- set the "sheet settings" locale to "Italian"
- create and run the following script

```
function main() {
  var csvContent= 'code;value\n01mmabc001;111,1\n21mar003;222,2';
  var separator= ';';
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent,separator);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range;
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("IMPORT");
  range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length);
  range.setValues(csvData);
}
```

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would actually help. I created a `csv` string like that `var csvString = "a21MAR003,b,c\nd,e,f";` and then `var data = Utilities.parseCsv(csvString, ',');` and it worked perfectly fine. Maybe it is because of the source `csv` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to do it by changing this:

`range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length);`

to this:

`range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setNumberFormat('@');`

What this does is while getting the range it sets the format of the cells to `@`:

> Inserts the raw text for the cell, if the cell has text input. Not compatible with any of the other special characters and won’t display for numeric values (which are displayed as general format).

Reference:

[setNumberFormat(numberFormat)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)

[Number format tokens](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_tokens)